# Probability Measure for $X=Y$

Tags: probability, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X=Y$ be uniform random variables on $[0,1]$. I wonder if it's possible to define a probability measure rigorously on $[0,1] \times[0,1]$ so that all the Borel sets in  $[0,1] \times[0,1]$ are measurable. Apparently, this problem will be trivial if image of Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ under $\phi:(x,y) \to x$ is Borel. But this is false. But is image under this projection from intersection of any Borel set with line y=x measurable? If not, what is the best way to define a measure for $(X,Y)$ that matches our intuition of dependence here? that is, discarding as few as Borel sets in our definition of measurable sets (not necessarily a sigma algebra) as possible.

To give an example, we may define measurable sets as consisting of only rectangles in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. We know that intersection of any rectangle with $y=x is just an interval, which we can measure easily. But this restriction is quite limited. I wonder if there is a standard solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define it on a $\pi$-system $\Pi$ of rectangles $((a,b]\times(c,d])\cap[0,1]^2\subseteq [0,1]^2$.

- Extend to a ring $\mathcal{R}$ using countable additivity, then Caratheodory's extension theorem guarantees the existence of a measure on $\sigma$-algebra
- Dynkin's $\pi$-$d$ lemma (or if you prefer to call it $\pi$-$\lambda$ lemma) to get a unique measure defined on $\sigma(\Pi)=\mathcal{B}([0,1]^2)$.

Comment: Dynkins's lemma may be applied to show that if two probability measures that measure rectangles ``correctly'' then they yield identical measurements for all Borel sets. It says nothing about existence of such measures, which was the question.

Comment: Oops, yes you are right.  You need Caratheodory for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the product measure is all you need. ( I.e. for identically distributed uniform distributions)

If $X=Y$ is taken literally, only the diagonal $\Delta$ has positive measure. Then, if $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$, we can define $\mu(A) = \lambda(\pi[A\cap \Delta])$ where $\pi$ is one of the projections and $A$ is Borel in the  square.

Comment: I can see how to define $(X,Y)$ where $X,Y$ are independent. But as to the given condition X=Y, would you mind detailing your approach?

Comment: @DanielLi see the extra stuff

Comment: I thought this approach may not work since $A \cap \Delta$ may not be Lebesgue measurable in $1D$. Can you prove otherwise?

Comment: @DanielLi $\Delta$ is Borel in the square and $\pi$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: I cannot find a theorem that says image of a Borel set under homeomorphic map is measurable. Do you mind providing a source/proof for this?

Comment: @DanielLi it’s a straightforward proof. Bijections preserve set operations and images of opens are open etc.

Comment: How does this provide a valid proof? --we know that a Borel set cannot be simply written as union/intersection of open or closed sets. In fact there are counterexamples showing that image of projection here needs not to be Borel.

Comment: @DanielLi the images of Borel sets form a $\sigma$-algebra in the image, and they contain all open sets, so all Borel sets too. With the inverse function we see that it’s exactly the Borel sets of the image.